# Rails 3.1 OmniAuth with Facebook - Failure, but dont send error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I'm facing a weird problem.

I followed this tutorial : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

It works perfectly with the exact same code on my local machine (with modification on APP_ID and SECRET).

But when I test it on another server, I cant get logged in with Facebook informations...

I click on the link (<%= link_to 'register with fb', user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>) then I'm redirected well to Facebook which asks me if I allow the app and finally I get redirected to my site.

But I'm redirected to /user/sign_in ! And no record with the user retrieved from Facebook is created.

The log gives me :

> Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 192.168.1.254 at 2011-07-25 19:06:11 +0400
>
> Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=grV09GQr[...]BbcM-mxklOu5E"
>
> for 192.168.1.254 at 2011-07-25 19:06:12 +0400   Processing by
>   Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML   Parameters:
>
> {"code"=>"grV09GQrqjDepasyQpVhqSg0FINlr4h9[...]sSUooMrBRxBbcM-mxklOu5E"}
>
> Redirected to http://mysite.com/users/sign_in Completed 302 Found in
>   1ms

Someone has an idea ?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the sign-in page because this is the default behavior for the omniauth gem when an error occurs from facebook.  You are getting rejected from facebook.  If you were to decode the code in the returned URL, you might be able to figure out the reason.  It would be helpful if the error handler did that.

With facebook connect you must put the url of your website in the facebook configuration.  It is the canvas URL or web site url/domain in the configuration. If you don't have this set correctly, then facebook will reject your return request.

Comment: I found this question because I had a similiar error.  Turned out I had not entered my api-key correctly.  Make sure you have both the key and secret entered correctly in your configuration as well.  Note that what I mentioned above means that for each place you stage your server that has a different domain you need a different facebook app (i.e. localhost vs. example.com vs test.com).  If you do test.example.com for your test site there is a place in facebook for that though